# Error demoting Server 2008 R2 domain controller

Tags: active-directory, domain-controller

I have a domain that is at functional level 2008 R2 running on a 2008 R2 DC.

- joined a new 2019 server to the domain
- added AD services role to the 2019 server
- migrated FRS to DFSR on 2008 R2
- promoted 2019 to DC
- promoted it to a Domain controller
- moved fsmo roles to 2019 server

All of above completed successfully.  When I attempted to demote the 2008 R2 server with DCPromo, I received a dialog with the following text.

---

The operation failed because:
Active Directory Domain Services could not transfer the remaining data in directory partition DC=DomainDnsZones,CD=CVV,DC=local to Active Directory Domain Controller \CVV-2K19.CVV.local.

"The directory service is missing mandatory configuration information, and is unable to determine the ownership of floating single-master operation roles."

---

I am running this in a test environment on Hyper-V images.  I have checkpoints saved at each stage.  If anyone has any insight I would appreciate any advice.

Comment: run the fsmo query on both sides. on 2008 it could be necessary that you use the gui tools. I had a similar condition and the 2008 did not transfer the fsmo roles. and on a other migration the old DC died during the progress. we had then move it dirty to the new one

Comment: Starting with 2008 R2, you can simply delete the DC using AD Users and Computers or AD Sites and Services.

Comment: Also you can seize the roles using ntdsutil.

Comment: The fsmo query on 2008R2 shows all 5 roles successfully moved to 2019.  The interesting thing is that neither domain controller shows on Users and Computers on 2008 but both show on 2019.  Both servers do show under Default-First-Site-Name on Sites and Services on both 2008R2 and 2019.  I just checked the original live server in production and Users and Computers does not show anything under Domain Controllers.  The original domain has the 2008R2 and also the definition for an old 2003 server which is no longer offline.  Maybe the domain is already corrupted?  How do I use ntdsutil?

Comment: I was able to remove the 2008R2 controller with the /forceremoval switch.  I then opened AD Sites and Services and deleted the NTDS settings and then the 2008R2 controller under servers which allowed me to raise the functional forest and domain level on the new controller.  Is there anything else that should be cleaned up?